# How to create a NestJS global exception filter for microservices?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I've just made a Global Exception filter that looks exactly like this on Nests documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

It catches just about everything but stuff outside Nest's life cycle, so I was wondering, how do I create a Global filter for exceptions that are not caught by that filter, like Nest's Microservices (kafka transport) events?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application#sharing-configuration), it mean http with rpc microservice, then global filter is using for http only. To share global config, you must set `inheritAppConfig: true`

rpc-exception.filter.ts

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { KafkaContext, RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  async catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const hostType = host.getType(); // 'rpc'
    const context = host.switchToRpc().getContext<KafkaContext>();
    return throwError(() => new RpcException(exception));
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
app.connectMicroservice(
{
  transport: Transport.KAFKA,
  options: {
    client: config.KAFKA_CLIENT_CONFIG,
    consumer: {
      groupId: config.MODULE_ALIAS,
    },
  },
} as KafkaOptions,
{ inheritAppConfig: true });
```